# Problems while connecting to two MongoDBs via Spring

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I'm trying to achieve to connect to two different MongoDBs with Spring (1.5.2. --> we included Spring in an internal Framework therefore it is not the latest version yet) and this already works partially but not fully. More precisely I found a strange behavior which I will describe below after showing my setup.

So this is what I done so far:

Project structure

```
backend
    config
    domain
        customer
        internal
    repository
        customer
        internal
    service
```

In `config`I have my Mongoconfigurations.

I created one base class which extends `AbstractMongoConfiguration`. This class holds fields for database, host etc. which are filled with the properties from a application.yml. It also holds a couple of methods for creating `MongoClient` and `SimpleMongoDbFactory`.

Furthermore there are two custom configuration classes. For each MongoDB one config. Both extend the base class.

Here is how they are coded:

Primary Connection

```
@Primary
@EntityScan(basePackages = "backend.domain.customer")
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(
        basePackages = {"backend.repository.customer"}, 
        mongoTemplateRef = "customerDataMongoTemplate")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "customer.mongodb")
public class CustomerDataMongoConnection extends BaseMongoConfig{

    public static final String TEMPLATE_NAME = "customerDataMongoTemplate";

    @Override
    @Bean(name = CustomerDataMongoConnection.TEMPLATE_NAME)
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() {
        MongoClient client = getMongoClient(getAddress(), 
        getCredentials());
        SimpleMongoDbFactory factory = getSimpleMongoDbFactory(client, 
        getDatabaseName());
        return new MongoTemplate(factory);
    }
}
```

The second configuration class looks pretty similar. Here it is:

```
@EntityScan(basePackages = "backend.domain.internal")
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(
    basePackages = {"backend.repository.internal"}
    mongoTemplateRef = InternalDataMongoConnection.TEMPLATE_NAME
            )
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "internal.mongodb")
public class InternalDataMongoConnection extends BaseMongoConfig{

    public static final String TEMPLATE_NAME = "internalDataMongoTemplate";

    @Override
    @Bean(name = InternalDataMongoConnection.TEMPLATE_NAME)
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() {
        MongoClient client = getMongoClient(getAddress(), getCredentials());
        SimpleMongoDbFactory factory = getSimpleMongoDbFactory(client, 
        getDatabaseName());
        return new MongoTemplate(factory);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I use `EnableMongoRepositories`to define which repository should use which connection.

My repositories are defined just like it is described in the Spring documentation.

However, here is one example which is located in package `backend.repository.customer`:

```
public interface ContactHistoryRepository extends MongoRepository<ContactHistoryEntity, String> {
    public ContactHistoryEntity findById(String id);
}
```

The problem is that my backend always only uses the primary connection with this setup. Interestingly, when I remove the beanname for the `MongoTemplate` (just `@Bean`) the backend then uses the secondary connection (`InternalMongoDataConnection`). This is true for all defined repositories.

My question is, how can I achieve that my backend really take care of both connections? Probably I missed to set another parameter/configuration?

Since this is a pretty extensive post I apologise if I forgot something to mention. Please ask for missing information in the comments.

Comment: are you sure both your repository classes are in different packages/directories?. Also try to use `@Primary` on mongoTemplate() method instead of class level

Comment: @pvpkiran Thanks for your comment. I changed the `@Primary` annotation but this did not solve the problem. Regarding your repository question, yes both classes are in different packages.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
In my package structure there was a empty configuration class (of my colleague) with the annotation `@Configuration`and `@EnableMongoRepositories`. This triggered the automatic wiring process of Stpring Data and therefore led to the problems I reported above.
I simply deleted the class and now it works as it should!